# Linux mint not running

Tags: linux-mint

I have Linux mint installed on a usb drive and it will boot and display a menu with boot options. When I select Linux mint, the computer screen goes blank and my monitor looses connection like it didn't boot at all.

Comment: It will help to list your hardware, particularly motherboard and graphics card. Are you using UEFI or Legacy BIOS?

Comment: My motherboard is a Sabertooth 990fx r2.0 with an amd fx 8350

Comment: What is the maximum resolution supported by your monitor? Do the HDD activity LED still blinks after the screen goes blank? If you press the CAPS LOCK key does the LED go on and off?

Comment: My monitor is 1080p and I'm running Linux off a usb drive. I can boot back into windows by force shutting down my Pc and removing the usb drive. There is no lights on the usb drive that are on and the harddrive led is off. The keyboard lights work fine.

Comment: Have a look at this help guide for black screen in Mint, see if the suggestions help: https://community.linuxmint.com/tutorial/view/842. The nomodeset stuff is likely to fix it, sounds like it could be a GPU issue.

Comment: I'm still having the same problem. I added the line for nvidia cards and it still isn't booting

Comment: I will try ubuntu on another drive to see if that works

Answer (score 0):

I think your Linux tries to load the amd (i assume you have also an amd gpu) framebuffer, which is not able to run with several current kernels.

try to edit the bootline (hit `e` on your boot menu entry) and add

```
vga=normal nofb nomodeset
```

to it. one of it should disable the amd framebuffer and run without it.

Comment: I have an nvidia gtx 970

Comment: `nomodeset` will still do, and `nouveau` does no better than `radeon`, especially if your distro is not with recent (or, so called edgy) versions kernel. `modprobe.blacklist=nouveau` instead if you want to be specific. not sure `vga=normal nofb` make any point though.

Answer (score 0):

It is not booting because of the usb drive. I tried another and it worked fine. It might be because it is usb 3 or has an improper file system